# How to use transaction in apache camel route which involves SFTP and database

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel, camel-ftp

I am trying to achieve the following in the apache camel route

1. Read data from database
2. generate files from the data
3. send the generated files to SFTP endpoint
4. save the generated file to the database.

I want to make transacted for step 3 and 4 so that files which are sent are always stored in the database and vice versa. any suggestions how achieve that?

I have tried using the transacted in the route files which are sent to SFTP endpoint and not reverted even though if it fails in step 4.

Comment: the sftp endpoint is not transactional, so you won't be able to get this functionality.

Comment: can we achieve this if route has MQ endpoint instead of SFTP? @DougGrove

Comment: yes you can.  We do it all of the time.

Comment: How to do that? even with MQ I am not able to achieve it, even though if it is transacted message sent to MQ is not reverted in case if there are failures after sending the message @DougGrove

Comment: This can actually be difficult to achieve.  If you are using Spring Boot, for example, then you may need to configure a JTA transaction manager. (well, you will need a JTA transaction manager installed as the PlatformTransactionManager regardless of your platform).  I have some older examples on github:  https://github.com/grovedc/CamelSpringJMS    Have a look at the pom.xml files and the camel-context.xml files.  Note as well the use of the Red Hat bom.xml files to get consistent artifacts.

Comment: Develop a custom kamelet and get it done the way you like